# "Visual Studio has added the full set of dependencies for ASP.NET MVC 5 to project" Can I reverse it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

By mistake I create a MVC 5 Controler instead Web Api 2 Controller in my .NET Web API Project and I received the following message:

> Visual Studio has added the full set of dependencies for ASP.NET MVC 5
>   to project 'PROJECT_NAME'.
>
> The Global.asax.cs file in the project may require additional changes
>   to enable ASP.NET MVC.
>
> 1. Add the following namespace references:
>
>    using System.Web.Mvc;
>      using System.Web.Routing;
>      using System.Web.Optimization;
> 2. If the code does not already define an Application_Start method, add the following method:
>
>    protected void Application_Start()
>      {
>      }
> 3. Add the following lines to the end of the Application_Start method:
>
>    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
>      RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
>      FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
>      BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

Is there a simple way to reverse this? Do I have to delete unnecessary files and dependencies one by one manually? Will previously created Api controllers work without changes?

Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using source control, right? So you can just undo the changes? Otherwise, yes to "Do I have to delete unnecessary files and dependencies one by one manually?"

Comment: Yes I use, but I have not committed the last changes (a few hours of work - I know, my fault ;( ). Thanks for answer.

Comment: You don't have to undo all your changes.  Should only be the project file that needs reverting.  Do a diff to check for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using any form of source control like Git or TFVC you can just undo the changes.

Otherwise, unfortunately, yes to:

> Do I have to delete unnecessary files and dependencies one by one manually?"

Comment: Yes I use, but I have not committed the last changes (a few hours of work - I know, my fault ;( ). Thanks for answer.

Comment: Hmm.. that s*cks. Fortunately it doesn't mess with any of your custom code. So chances are you're good to go in no time.